# what's the meaning of this program?

Tags: python

I know that the program convert Decimal to Binary,in fact I'm just a beginner in programming and python is my starting language.

answering these questions will help me a lot.

```
def bin(i):
    s = "" # what do we mean by s="" ? does it mean s=0?
    while i: # where is the condition ? 
        if i & 1: # what is the equivalent for '&'? when I put 'and' instead of '&' I get differnt results?why?
            s = "1" + s # ?
        else:
            s = "0" + s
        i = i//2 # why?
    return s
```

the problem  is that I want to undestand what  happen between the input and the output?
one more thing can we extend this code to floating numbers how ?

Comment: *"what do we mean by s="" ? does it mean s=0"* No. It means `s = ""`, i.e. assign an empty string to `s`.

Comment: What, if any, effort have *you put* into understanding this? Added any `print`s? Tried anything in the interpreter? Read the documentation or a tutorial?

Comment: *"# what is the equivalent for '&'? when I put 'and' instead of '&' I get differnt results?why?"*, because `&` is binary and and `and` is logical 'and'

Comment: I don't agree with this question beeing too broad. It's very basic, true, but there are 5 sub-questions that are all easily answered (see answers...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to answer your questions one at a time; you should then be able to piece them all together:

```
s = "" # what do we mean by s="" ? does it mean s=0?
```

`s` is now an empty string. You could add other strings to it, to concatenate them. Indeed, this is what is done later on, in the line `s = "1" + s`. Take a look:

```
In [21]: "1" + ""
Out[21]: '1'

In [22]: "1" + "2"
Out[22]: '12'

In [23]: s = ""

In [24]: "1" + s
Out[24]: '1'
```

See how string concatenation works?

**Next**:

```
while i: # where is the condition ?
```

Ah! there is a nuance in many programming languages (including python) that an integer whose value is `0` evaluates to a boolean of `False`, when used in a conditional statement (like `if` or `while`). All non-zero values evaluate to `True`.

Therefore, this while loop is saying `while i does not take the value of 0`. Note that because of the division on `i` later on, `i` will never take on a negative value, and this loop therefore terminates.

**Next**:

```
if i & 1: # what is the equivalent for '&'? when I put 'and' instead of '&' I get differnt results?why?
```

`i&1` is a bit-wise AND operator. Suppose `i` has the value of `5`. Then, the binary representation of `i` is `101`. the binary representation of `1` is simply `1`, or `001` (since we are comparing it with `101`). So now, we perform the bit-wise AND, which basically compares each pair of corresponding bits, outputting `1` if they are both `1`s (`0` otherwise). The result of comparing `101` and `001` thusly, is `001`, which translates to a value of `1`. All this means is that when you divide `i` by `2`, you get a remainder of `1`. Since the only possibilities for this are `1` (which evaluates to `True` in the if-statement) or `0` (which evaluates to `False` in the if-statement), it lends itself to be very easily used in such a dichotomous fashion (to add either a `"0"` or a `"1"` to `s`)

**Next**:

```
i = i//2
```

This is a truncated division with an integer casting. Watch:

```
In [27]: i = 4

In [28]: i/2
Out[28]: 2.0

In [29]: i//2
Out[29]: 2

In [30]: i = 5

In [31]: i/2
Out[31]: 2.5

In [32]: i//2
Out[32]: 2
```

Get it?

Comment: Nice! You beat me to it :)